# Parsing Comments and saving them in temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, parsing

Via the frontend of a certain software package, administrators can add tags to each users in the system in a free textfield (called Comments).

```
[teamlead:tom] [diet:vegan] [location:munich]
```

I know it would be much better if we could simply add columns to the Users table to add metadata to users, but we do not have this possibility.

I now need to query this free textfield, and basically query:

```
select userid, username, diet from Users where diet is not null;
```

For this, I have to parse the text in Comments, but I am unsure what the best approach is.

Can I do the parsing live in the query (table only has a few hundred users so performance should not be an issue)?

Does something like this require a 2-step process? For instance, first building a temp table with all values? If so, how could I parse the comments and build a temp table for all tags for each user?

Answer (score 1):

First, for your example query, you don't actually have to parse the comments.  You can use `like` to look for keywords:

```
where comments like '%![diet:%' escape '!'
```

For a vegan diet:

```
where comments like '%![diet:vegan!]%' escape '!'
```

Of course, actually parsing the comments is desirable.  The simplest way is to look for a `split()` function on the web (Google:  "SQL Server split").  You can then use that to split the values.  You might also find a way to convert these strings to XML, which would be an alternative approach.

Comment: I would actually need a query that outputs the diet for each user (so: `1   daniel   vegan   |   2   peter   vegetarian   |   3   renee   normal`) etc. Sorry if I wasn't clear at first.

Comment: @Pr0no . . . I suspected as much, which is why I suggest that you find a `split()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Output') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #Output

CREATE TABLE #Output
    (UserID INT IDENTITY(1, 1),
     username NVARCHAR(MAX),
     diet NVARCHAR(MAX))

INSERT INTO #Output
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Comments, CHARINDEX('[teamlead:', Comments, 1), CHARINDEX(']', Comments)), '[teamlead:', ''), ']', ''),
       REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(Comments, CHARINDEX('[diet:', Comments, 1), CHARINDEX(']', Comments, 20) - LEN(SUBSTRING(Comments, CHARINDEX('[teamlead:', Comments, 1), CHARINDEX(']', Comments)))), '[diet:', ''), ']', '')
FROM Users
```